# Remove x random entries from a vector

Tags: r

I have a large vector:

```
a<-1:1000
a<-sample(a,replace=F)
b<-sample(1:10,1)
```

I would like to randomly remove '`b`' number of entries from `a`. How can this be done?

Comment: `adel <- a[-sample(seq_along(a),size=b,replace=FALSE))]`

Comment: note `replace=FALSE` is the default, but sometimes handy to leave in for clarity when you cant remember what the default is.

Comment: Remove the frist element of `a` or a random element of `a` is the same if `a` is scrambled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Length of a is irrelevant, lets make a shorter example:

```
> a=1:20
> a=sample(a,replace=FALSE)
> a
 [1]  9 11 16 15 10 18  8  7  4  2 14  5 12 20  6  1 13 19  3 17
> b=sample(1:10,1)
> b
[1] 3
> a=a[-sample(1:length(a),b)]
> a
 [1]  9 11 16 15 10 18  7  4  2 14 12 20  6  1 13 19  3
> length(a)
[1] 17
```

the trick here is to take a sample of length b from 1:length(a) and then use negative indexing to subset.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to set `b` values from `a` to be `NA`, then:

```
a[sample(1:length(a), b)] <- NA
```

If you want to remove `b` values from `a`, then:

```
a <- a[-sample(1:length(a), b)]
```